# Merging two ActiveRecord associations collections into single Association collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I am having a Post model where users can add posts similar to facebook.

In newsfeed i want to show them in descending order with respect to created_at.

The problem is

```
current_user.posts
```

returns his/her posts whereas

```
current_user.networks.each {|network| network.connection.posts}
```

returns his connection's posts.

I want to combine both the results so that i can write something like

```
all_posts.order(created_at: :desc)
```

or is there a better way to do it?

**EDIT**

With codes

**user.rb**

```
has_many :posts
```

**post.rb**

```
belongs_to :user
```

**network.rb**

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :connection, class_name: 'User'
```

where network model is a joint and self-referential model and has *user_id* and *connection_id* columns and it updates when both users become friends.

Comment: what are the association between post/connection/user?

Comment: @AndreyDeineko No. between user's posts and his friend's aka connection's posts.

Comment: @AndreyDeineko Okay. I will edit question with the codes.

Comment: how looks connection.rb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
user_post_ids = current_user.post_ids
connection_post_ids = []
current_user.networks.each do |network|
  connection_post_ids += network.connection.post_ids
end
post_ids = user_post_ids + connection_post_ids

all_posts = Post.where(id: post_ids).order(created_at: :desc)
```

Comment: Okay. Will try.

Comment: current_user.post_ids works but for connection_post_ids i am getting undefined method `post_ids' for #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQLAdapter:0x00007fba958160f8> error.

Comment: Hi..its working for connections too with following code: <% current_user.networks.each {|network| connection_post_ids.push network.connection.post_ids} %> where connection_post_ids = [] declared as empty array. However now the result has two arrays [[45,34,54,24,53]]. Can you please help how to remove one array.

Comment: if array =  [[45,34,54,24,53]] then call array.flatten to remove the outer array brackets